# three dimension and maxima and minima

Tags: calculus

Suppose $0\leq \alpha, \beta, \gamma\leq \pi$ and $\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma = 1$, then what is the maximum and minimum of $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$.

Comment: How about using Lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 1):

Put
$$\alpha:={\pi\over2}+x,\quad \beta:={\pi\over2}+y,\quad \gamma:={\pi\over2}+z\ .$$
Then maximizing/minimizing $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ under the constraints
$$\cos^2\alpha+\cos^\beta+\cos^2\gamma=1,\qquad\alpha,\ \beta,\ \gamma\in[0,\pi]$$ is the same as maximizing $$s(x,y,z):=x+y+z$$
under the constraints
$$g(x,y,z):=\sin^2 x+\sin^2 y+\sin^2 z=1,\qquad x,\ y,\ z\in\left[-{\pi\over2},{\pi\over2}\right]\ .\tag{1}$$
The equation $g(x,y,z)=1$ defines a surface $S\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ with the symmetries of an octahedron. In fact $S$ contains the $12$ edges of an octahedron with diameter $\pi$; see the following figure.

[image]

Inspecting this figure we come to the tentative conclusion that $s$ is maximal when $x=y=z>0$, which leads to $\sin^2 x={1\over3}$, or $x=\arcsin{1\over\sqrt{3}}$. Therefore we conjecture
$$s_{\rm max}=3\arcsin{1\over\sqrt{3}}\doteq1.84644>{\pi\over2}\ ,\tag{2}$$
and because of the inherent symmetry we would have $s_{\rm min}=-s_{\max}$. The two extremal values of $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ would then be ${3\pi\over2}$ smaller than the corresponding extremal values of $s$.

In order to prove $(2)$ we note
$$\nabla g(x,y,z)=\bigl(\sin(2x),\sin(2y),\sin(2z)\bigr)\ .$$
It follows that the only points  ${\bf p}\in S$ where $\nabla g({\bf p})={\bf 0}$ are the six vertices of the octahedron. The values of $s$ in these points are $\pm{\pi\over2}$, i.e., not exceeding $(2)$. All other points of $S$ are regular points of $g$, and  Lagrange's method can be used to bring the conditionally stationary points of $s$  to the fore. One computes
$$\nabla s-\lambda\nabla g=\bigl(1-\lambda\sin(2x),1-\lambda\sin(2y),1-\lambda\sin(2z)\bigr)\ .$$
It follows that at a conditionally stationary point one has
$$\sin(2x)=\sin(2y)=\sin(2z)\ne0\ .\tag{3}$$
This implies that there is a $u\in\bigl[0,{\pi\over4}\bigr]$ with
$$x={\pi\over 4}\pm u,\quad y={\pi\over 4}\pm u, \quad z={\pi\over 4}\pm u$$
or the opposite of these. A priori  the $\pm$-signs can be chosen independently. But two or more $+$-signs immediately lead to a violation of $(1)$, and $x={\pi\over 4}+ u$, $\> y={\pi\over 4}- u$ implies $\sin^2 x+\sin^2 y=1$, whence $\sin z=0$, which is forbidden by $(3)$. This allows us to conclude that in fact
$$x=y=z={\pi\over 4}- u\ ,$$
and using $(1)$ we arrive at the conjectured solution $(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the second derivative of $\cos^2 x $ is $- 2 \cos 2x$. It is negative on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2} ]$ and positive on $[\frac{\pi}{2}, 0 ]$

To find the maximum, notice that if $\alpha, \beta, \gamma < \frac{\pi}{2} $, then you can replace the corresponding term by $\pi - \alpha, \pi - \beta, \pi - \gamma$ and leave $\sum \cos^2=1$ while increasing the linear sum. Hence, we may assume that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi ]$, and then apply [Jensens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Similarly, for the minimum, we can show that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2} ] $, and apply Jensens.

Comment: The second derivative of $\cos^2 x$ is $-2\cos(2x)$.

Comment: The first line should be: it is positive on $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]\cup[\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi]$...

Comment: @metacompactness That is right. And in which case, this approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just some geometric intuition: if $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the angles that a vector makes with the 3 positive coordinate axes, these formulas will hold. What Calvin said, about "increasing the linear sum", is saying that there's no point in considering all acute angles: if you fix two angles, the valid options for the third angle are the angles formed when the two cones intersect. One will be acute with the third axis (i.e. be where the current vector is) and the other will be obtuse; clearly the obtuse case is larger.

The expression is symmetric in all 3 variables. Therefore a *unique* maximum or minimum must lie on the axis of symmetry: parallel to the vector $(1,1,1)$. It's clear to see which direction (positive or negative) gives you the maximum and which gives you the minimum. The tricky part would then lie in proving that there is a unique maximum/minimum. Formal methods of inequalities would probably be your best bet here.